# How to fix "eslint(no-unused-vars)" in vue script

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to run a server in a  Vuejs App but i have troubles with eslint message appreciate your help to fix them

This is my Json file:

```
 {
   "name": "blog-frontend",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
 },
  "dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.19.0",
   "core-js": "^3.3.2",
   "vue": "^2.6.10",
   "vue-router": "^3.0.6"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
   "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.0.0",
   "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
   "eslint": "^5.16.0",
   "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
   "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
 }
}
```

This is the message on console:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                             5:11:39 PM
 error  in ./src/views/Home.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'server' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src\views\Home.vue:40:9:
  38 | <script>
  39 | // @ is an alias to /src
> 40 | import {server} from "@/utils/helper";
     |         ^
  41 | import axios from "axios";
  42 |
  43 | export default {


error: 'id' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src\views\Home.vue:58:16:
  56 |         .then(data => (this.posts = data.data));
  57 |     },
> 58 |     deletePost(id) {
     |                ^
  59 |       axios.delete('${sever.baseURL}/blog/delete?postID=${id}').then(data => {
  60 |         console.log(data);
  61 |         window.location.reload();


2 errors found.

 @ ./src/router.js 3:0-41 19:15-28
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.152:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

**Home.vue**

```
<script>
 // @ is an alias to /src
 import {server} from "@/utils/helper";
 import axios from "axios";

export default {
 data() {
  return {
   posts: []
 };
},
created() {
 this.fetchPosts();
},
methosd: {
 fetchPosts() {
  axios
    .get('${server.baseURL}/blog/posts')
    .then(data => (this.posts = data.data));
},
deletePost(id) {
  axios.delete('${sever.baseURL}/blog/delete?postID=${id}').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    window.location.reload();
   });
  }
 }
};
</script>
```

**helper.js**

```
export const server = {
 baseURL: 'http:localhost:3000'
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
 router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

*I expect that enough info and you can help me to fix them*

Comment: `methosd` should be `methods` and in `deletePost`, you have `sever` instead of `server`

Comment: Also, you're using single-quotes for your [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but they should be backticks, ie `\`${server.baseURL}/blog/posts\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string template to build your url correctly like below;

```
axios.delete(`${server.baseURL}/blog/delete?postID=${id}`).then(data => {
```

Then `server` and `id` will be used and errors will be fixed.